# Loading jQuery UI with delegate() or live()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using `.load()` to load other pages within my site into a `div`. Is there a way to add jquery ui enhancements to elements on the newly loaded page? I was thinking about using `.delegate()` or `.live()`, but can't figure out what event to bind them to? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callback functions provided by jQuery's ajax function - for `load()`, the syntax would look something like:

```
$('#ele').load('somewhere #newEle', function(){
    $(this).find('#newEle').slider();
});
```

Alternatively, look at the global ajax events, like [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) or use a plugin that extends jQuery's existing ajax functions with functionality like the one you need such as this one: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/

Answer (score 1):

You want to do you jQuery UI code in the `complete` callback.  See [the API](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  For example:

```
$('#myDiv').load('/some/page.html', function() {
    // jQuery UI hotness here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate to bind the events to the div you are loading content to, so if your div has an id of `somediv` then you would bind them like so...

```
$('#somediv').delegate('a', 'click', function() {

})
.delegate('input', 'focusin', function() {

})
.delegate('li', 'click', function() {

});
```

These are obviously just made up examples... but you can chain your handlers like this and bind them to your content loading div.

Enjoy :)